# MonoDevelop in OS-X , trying to create a solution with more than one project

Tags: macos, mono, monodevelop

I want to create a solution with more than one project in it. But I cannot find how I can add a second project (existing already)

Thank,
IGnacio

Answer (score 3):

Right click your solution in the "Solution" window, and do Add -> Add New Project or Add Existing Project.